# Total in the jmeter summary report

Tags: jmeter

I have created a new test  and in the summary it shows a total and the average response time is 76ms. I have a question regarding this TOTAL. On what basis they are calculating the total. Is it possible to load a page and do some actions which results less than 1 sec. Here i got 76 ms. Can any one please answer?

Comment: I don't know how it's calculated, but yes it is very possible to do a lot of actions within one second. Remember that a second is made up of 1000 milliseconds, so the 76ms average that you get is actually well under 1 second (0.076 seconds).

Comment: One more doubt. I am using jmeter 4.0. I have run a test with 10 users and that test ran successfully. But in the summary report , I couldn't see the report of load testing. I can see only the report of one user which i recorded earlier. It will ask once we click on run option in the top, then i have selected append to the existing file option. But till now i couldn't see the report for 10 user load testing